# Undefined EXEC method in PhoneGap 2.0

Tags: android, cordova

When trying to execute a phonegap plugin method, the application raises this error:

> `TypeError 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'cordova.exec( ...`

Code included in app:

**Javascript plugin link (file settingswrite.js)**

```
window.SettingsWrite = function(objectData, successCallback, failureCallback) {

    var options = {};
    for (var key in objectData) {
      options[key] = objectData[key];
    }
    cordova.exec(
                successCallback,
                failureCallback,
                'SettingsWrite',
                'set',
                new Array(options)
            );
    };
```

**Javascript code to make use of plugin (file app.js)**

```
function setActualPosition() {

    // appMap is an application global object
    var map = appMap.getMapEdgesProjection();

    window.SettingsWrite([{
            x: map.minh,
            y: map.maxh
    }], 
    function(r){
       alert(r);
    },
    function(e){
         alert("Operation error");
         console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
    });
}
```

Plugin is declared in config.xml as:

```
<plugin name="SettingsWrite" value="es.mycompany.cordova.plugin.SettingsWrite"/>
```

Javascript code is executed index.html (located at assets folder and included into WebView):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Test Mobile</title>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

        <script src="assets/js/cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/settingswrite.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="divMapContainer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the plugin Java class (as defined in Phonegap docs):

```
public class SettingsWrite extends Plugin {

     public static final String ACTION = "set";

     @Override
     public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray data, String callbackId) {

           if(ACTION.equals(action)) {
            .
            .
            .
           } else {
            .
            .
            .
           }
     }
```

The plugin runs in Android 3.1 device and all needed files are correctly included to the project(cordova-2.0.0.js and cordova-2.0.0.jar). May someone help me?

Comment: Paste Some code so that we see wot u did actually...

Comment: Done! Thanks in advance for all your help and support

Comment: @EsteveCamps did you got solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

At what point are you calling `setActualPosition`? Has the `deviceready` event fired? If it has not fired, you will not have access to the `cordova` objects.

Comment: I set a listener for deviceready event but it seems to never reach that point.

Comment: Try removing your plugin and see if the deviceready event fires. As mentioned in the answer you cannot use any cordova object until that event fires.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you. There is a fix in this post:

[datePicker plugin not working in Phonegap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776905/datepicker-plugin-not-working-in-phonegap-2-0/11792305#11792305)

Comment: I already changed the plugin code to cordova.getActivity() but error does not disappear