# PhoneGap 2.0 (Cordova) DatePicker PlugIn 'mode'-Property to get Date AND Time

Tags: javascript, cordova, datepicker, phonegap-plugins, android-datepicker

Today I started creating my first (Android-)App with PhoneGap, using the [DatePicker-Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker). After some hours of investigation I've got it to work (thanks to [datePicker plugin not working in Phonegap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776905/datepicker-plugin-not-working-in-phonegap-2-0)) but not exactly I want:

I have an input with `class="nativedatepicker" (date)` (selector for the jQuery click-event) and one with `class="nativetimepicker" (time)` so I can choose in the first input the date and in the second the time.

Is it possible to merge this to one input where I can choose date and time in one step? I think I can do this somewhere here (some JS out of the PlugIn):

```
window.datePicker.show({
    date : myNewDate,
    mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
    allowOldDates : true
}
```

but when I leave the `mode` blank it throws an error.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

How do you leave it blank exactly ? 
If you do

```
mode : ,
```

You will get errors because the JS object needs a value for all keys you specify. You can try

```
mode : '',
```

Answer (score 0):

No, currently that is not possible using the current [DatePicker](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/DatePicker) plugin for android, even though they say that if you set the mode property to blank you will get both. You can see it in DatePickerPlugin.java file:

```
if (ACTION_TIME.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {       //mode is set to "time"
        //plugin java code
    } else if (ACTION_DATE.equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {         //mode is set to "date"
        //plugin java code
    } else {        //mode is blank
        Log.d(pluginName, "Unknown action. Only 'date' or 'time' are valid actions");
        return;
    }
```

My solution for the problem of selecting both date and time is to first show the date dialog and in the success callback show the time dialog.

The code looks like this:

```
        var showDialog = function(mode, date, cb) {

            window.plugins.datePicker.show({
                date : date,
                mode : mode
            }, function(dateStr) {
                cb(new Date(dateStr));
            });
        };

        $('.nativedatepicker').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var currentField = $(this);

            var oldDate = new Date(currentField.val()) || new Date();

            //show the dialog to select the date
            showDialog("date", oldDate, function(newDate) {

                //we have a new date selected, copy time values from the old date for time dialog
                newDate.setHours(oldDate.getHours());
                newDate.setMinutes(oldDate.getMinutes());

                //show the time dialog          
                showDialog("time", newDate, function(newDateTime) {

                    //now we have time selected, copy it to new date and update the field
                    newDate.setHours(newDateTime.getHours());
                    newDate.setMinutes(newDateTime.getMinutes());
                    currentField.val(newDate.toISOString());
                });

            });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my alternative solution to DZL's answer. I have the date and time hooked up to two separate buttons that both alter the same date:

```
 var date = new Date();
 var $date = $('#date_result');

  var normalizeNumber = function(n){
    var c = parseInt(n, 10); 
    return (c<10) ? "0"+c : c; 
 }

 var normalizeTime = function(t){
    var hours = t.getHours();
    var minutes = t.getMinutes();
    var meridiem = ' AM ';
    if (hours > 12) {
        hours -= 12;
        meridiem = ' PM ';
    } else if (hours === 0) {
       hours = 12;
    }
    minutes =  normalizeNumber(minutes);
    return hours + ':' + minutes + meridiem; 
 }

$('#date-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    var myNewDate = date;
    if(typeof myNewDate === "number"){ myNewDate = new Date (myNewDate); }
    window.plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewDate,
        mode : 'date',
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        newDate.setMinutes(date.getMinutes());
        newDate.setHours(date.getHours());
        date = newDate;
        $date.val(newDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + normalizeTime(newDate));
        $date.blur();
    });
});

$('#time-btn').on('click', function(event) {
    var myNewTime = date;
    if(typeof myNewTime === "number"){ myNewTime = new Date (myNewTime); }
    plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewTime,
        mode : 'time',
        allowOldDates : true
    }, function(returnDate) {
        var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
        newDate.setDate(date.getDate());
        newDate.setMonth(date.getMonth());
        newDate.setFullYear(date.getFullYear());            
        date = newDate;
        $date.val(newDate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + normalizeTime(newDate));     
        $date.blur();
    });
});
```