# Phonegap Datepicker plugin on Android

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker

I am using the Phonegap Datepicker plugin for Android.

I am not able to see the datepicker when I open the screen. I am getting this error.

09-13 22:37:55.894: E/Web Console(13123): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'show' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:689

My code looks like:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup">
    <p>
        <label for="airportName">Airport</label> <input type="text" name="airportName" id="airportName" class="custom" />
        <label for="selectDate">Date</label> <input type="text" name="selectDate" id="selectDate" class="nativedatepicker" />            
    </p>
```

and I have the used the event handler like

```
$('.nativedatepicker').click(function(event) {
    var currentField = $(this);
    var myNewDate = Date.parse(currentField.val()) || new Date();

    // Same handling for iPhone and Android
    window.plugins.datePicker.show({
        date : myNewDate,
        mode : 'date', // date or time or blank for both
        allowOldDates : true
        }, function(returnDate) {
            var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
            currentField.val(newDate.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

            // This fixes the problem you mention at the bottom of this script with it not working a second/third time around, because it is in focus.
            currentField.blur();
    });
});
```

Is there any link where I can see an example of how this plug-in in used apart from the usual example shown in the documentation?

Comment: did you add plugin to plugin.xml ?!

Comment: What's your phonegap / cordova version?

Comment: Did you forget putting the datePickerPlugin.js file in www directory?

Answer (score 5):

The things you must do is to change `DatePickerPlugin.java` because if not with the new `Cordova 2.0` won't work.
After changing two lines in this file, calling from `Javascript` won't trouble you again.
Change:

```
  final DroidGap currentCtx = (DroidGap) ctx.getContext();
```

for this:

```
  final Context currentCtx = cordova.getActivity();
```

Find this:

```
  ctx.runOnUiThread(runnable);
```

and replace for:

```
  cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
```

Read this thread for further information:
[datePicker plugin not working in Phonegap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776905/datepicker-plugin-not-working-in-phonegap-2-0)

Comment: I change the code what u posted. Still i cant get Date. Im using cordova 2.2.0 and relevant js. Can u help me ?