# Android Datepicker Crash on Phonegap App

Tags: android

I'm working on an application for Android using phonegap

I have the input with type "date" which open android date picker.

But when I am trying to click set the selected date, the app crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this problem has not been solved yet, because OP used to forget paste theirs logs of errors. I believe that one day someone,  I don't know.. maybe you... will be so kind thay he will post his stactrace with his code so that we will be able help him so fast as we could..

Comment: Topic is duplicated you can refer here...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776905/datepicker-plugin-not-working-in-phonegap-2-0

Answer (score 1):

Hi Guys I figured out and **fixed the issue**. This is the cause of the problem which is mentioned here [Invoke native date picker from web-app on iOS/Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946919/invoke-native-date-picker-from-web-app-on-ios-android?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Apparently I had to pick a JS datepicker which looks like the native one to fix the issue. and of course the  needed to be changed to **"text"**

I used mobipick http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/ - it worked just great!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not fixed.
FYI this happens with the native datepicker (NO Plugin used). in my case I have 2 
if I pick any date for 1 the other doesnt work. it pops up the native datepicker but then if I press set it does nothing and after a while get frozen (static and I can't do anything & have to kill the app)

FYI - the web view (if I browse it from the browser) it works fine but not in the app. I used build.phonegap to build the app