# Error Replace ctx.getContext() with cordova.getContext()

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, monaca

i'm newbine in monaca project (http://monaca.mobi)
I want to use datepickerplugin to get date  but i get error "Replace ctx.getContext() with cordova.getContext()". I found help in [datePicker plugin not working in Phonegap 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776905/datepicker-plugin-not-working-in-phonegap-2-0) but i can not find file DatePickerPlugin.java to edit.

Any one can help me. thank you very much. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever go through the Monaca documentation website?

I found this http://docs.monaca.mobi/en/reference/phonegap_plugin/datepicker/ on the site talking about the datepicker plugin.

I hope this link would help you.